# Why can't I download the pdf in the WebView using DownloadListener?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview, android-download-manager

I can't seem to figure out why I can't download a PDF from the WebView. I get a download unsuccessful notification in the download manager of the Android device. However if I use a different URL domain, it downloads fine.

**Example that doesn't work:** http://somedomain/file.pdf and WebView loads from http://somedomain

**Example that works:** http://somedomain2/file.pdf and WebView loads from http://somedomain

**Fragment WebView Code with Download Listener:**

```
public class MyBillingFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyBillingFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static ProgressBar progressBar;
    private static WebView webView;
    private static View v;

    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT = 1;
    int requestCode;
    String[] permissions;
    int[] grantResults;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("MyBilling");
        if(v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_billing, container, false);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            } else {
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
                webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
                webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);


                webView.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient(){
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");

                    }
                });

                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                        if (progress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (progress == 100) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });

                webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                            switch (keyCode) {
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                                        webView.goBack();
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });

                String data = getActivity().getIntent().getDataString();

                if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getActivity().getIntent().getAction())) {
                    webView.loadUrl(data);
                } else {
                    webView.loadUrl("https://someurl");
                }


                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

                        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                            dm.enqueue(request);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "External storage permission required to save billing statements",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT);
                }


                if(requestCode == REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT){
                    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

                            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                dm.enqueue(request);
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "External write permission has not been granted, cannot save file.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                }

            }
        }

        return v;
    }



    public class ourViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.bringToFront();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you paste your webView code as well?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. If you debug the app, at what line does the app fail? does it throw an exception during executing your code? (Although I don't see your code being wrapped in an exception, so the OS might be throwing an exception.

Comment: Is webViewClient's onReceivedError() being called?

Comment: When I debug I don't see any exceptions in the Android Monitor. onReceivedError() is only being called when there is no internet connection. I'm still new at this.  Oh yeah another note, this works fine in SDK22. Just nothing at SDK23 and after can't download PDFs.

Comment: Never mind, I didn't have the correct monitor selected: I see this error message when I try to download the PDF. "05-16 15:34:08.317 2652-2652/ite.navigationdrawer W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2652"